# Need help to build dropdown fillup quiz in windows forms vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am beginner in vb.net Programming. I want to build dropdown fillup quiz where combobox position changes during run time according to the length of prefixed string. As fill location varies in different questions, so location of combobox cannot be fixed during different questons.

Comment: I am sorry  but this question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Make a start and when you run into a specific problem post again.

Comment: Thank @Mary  I have already done some part. But that is not an efficient way of doing this as it is using dedicated fixed windows form for each question. so, in that case, I need to create 100 windows form for 100 questions with a fixed ComboBox position. If I use the same windows form for all questions with fixed position of textBoxes and ComboBoxes, It overlaps during run time or does not show all text of the question. What I want to build is that  I attempt all questions on a single windows form. Like open 1st question attempt it, see the answer and move to next.

Comment: Use a label for the question. Set the max width property and the text will grow down and wrap. I have no idea how you want to use a combo box in a quiz.

Comment: it is like a simple quiz that has blank space. I need to place a ComboBox on the place of each blank space. So a question has comboBoxs equal to the number of blank space. Each ComboBox will contain 3 to 4 option and I need to select an option from particular a ComboBox to fill the blank space. I can design the windows form for a particular question. But in the next question, the position of blanks change.

Comment: So there in need to change the position of ComboBox.  If I make fixed Windows forms for each question,  this becomes very lengthy and less efficient. I want that when I click on the Next button, it loads the next question on a windows form and automatically adjusts the position of combo boxes according to the blank spaces. All questions saved in the database.

Comment: Okay, a fill in the blank quiz. Now I get it. I will have to think about this. Off hand, I would say this is a great idea but won't be easy. Is there a single combo box for each question?

Comment: No there are 4 to 5 Comboboxes. as I explained one Combobox for one blank space. Each Combobox contains 4 options to fill blank and only 1 option out of 4 is correct. I tried to do it by calculating the string length and setting the left property of Combobox equal to the calculating length of the string. But it only works if the length of the string is less than the max length of the windows form

Comment: If the length of the string is greater than the max length of windows form then I need to split the great part of a string to the next line and then place the combo box at the end of that string. But I know this is no accurate way of doing this. There is one more way is to CreateInstance to create dynamic objects during a run time like as we do in HTML. But I am not good at VB.net. I am just a beginner so finding it hard to create dynamic objects.

Comment: Hello @Mary did you get any idea. I am still solving this problem and unable to get a solution.

Comment: A FlowControlPanel might be what your want. A series of labels and comboboxes. Play around with it and see how it befaves.

Comment: Thank you@Mary for your help. I tried FlowControlPanel. It solved my problem to some extent. It arranges labels and Comboboxs perfectly if the length of each text less than the length of form or FlowControlPanel. But if The first Text string length crosses the length FlowControlPanel then Combobox got placed at the beginning of the next line and again next label got placed next line to the combo box.  I think to place all controls properly, none of the labels should have more than 1 line.

Comment: I think I can do this by splitting a string into substrings as per the remaining width of a particular line. Or there is any other way I can solve this problem. Secondly, I need to learn split string in substring as per the remaining width of FlowControlPanel.

Answer (score 1):

To build a quiz you need to create a Windows Form Application, in this case it will be in VB.net

You'll need to create an actual Windows Form Application, and to do that you'll use different objects in the toolbar when your Form App is open. There are different types of styles for a quiz, so if you want you can make it so that there is one question on the form app at a time, or you can fit all of it on one page, and add a submit button when the questions are all answered.

I've done different applications using several variables (which is what you need) to compare the answers to the per-determined answers in the code.

If you need more help, feel free to reply, and I can help you with the actual development of the application!

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Disarray. I want to build a question bank. Let suppose there is a 100 dropdown fillup question saved in a database such as SQL or access. When we run ques it loads 1st question with dropdown menu options. After completing the 1st question I can check for the correct option which highlights the wrong options selected. Then I move to the next question which will load the next question on the windows form. I have already done some part. But that is not an efficient way of doing this as it is using dedicated fixed windows form for each question.

Comment: But that is not an efficient way of doing this as it is using dedicated fixed windows form for each question. so, in that case, I need to create 100 windows form for 100 questions with a fixed ComboBox position. If I use the same windows form for all questions with fixed position of textBoxes and ComboBoxes, It overlaps during run time or does not show all text of the question. What I want to build is that  I attempt all questions on a single windows form. Like open 1st question attempt it, see the answer and move to next.